# Vspace is added in the wrong place

Tags: vertical-alignment, letters

I am using the latex letter class. I would like to add some vertical space after my address and before my phone number. This is the code I have:

```
\address{
    \textbf{Jonathan Hodgson} \\
    Address line 1,\\
    Address line 2,\\
    Address line 3,\\
    Address line 4,\\
    POST CODE \\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    Tel: \href{tel:+mynumber}{my number} \\
    Email: \email
}
```

For reasons unknown to me, the vspace is added between the telephone and email lines.

Changing the above to this:

```
\address{
    \textbf{Jonathan Hodgson} \\
    Address line 1,\\
    Address line 2,\\
    Address line 3,\\
    Address line 4,\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    POST CODE \\
    Tel: \href{tel:+mynumber}{my number} \\
    Email: \email
}
```

puts the space where I want it, after the post code.

This seems counter intuitive to me. Am I doing something wrong or is there a reason for this that I am missing.

Comment: Does `\\[0.2cm]` work?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, that does work. Are you able to explain why and what the difference is? I have never seen that sort of notation for vertical space before

Answer (score 5):

Macro `\\` usually supports an optional argument that specifies additional vertical space:

```
\address{
    \textbf{Jonathan Hodgson} \\
    Address line 1,\\
    Address line 2,\\
    Address line 3,\\
    Address line 4,\\
    POST CODE \\[0.2cm]
    Tel: \href{tel:+mynumber}{my number} \\
    Email: \email
}
```

The issue with `\vspace`: If it is put into horizontal mode, then the vertical is not set immediately (this is not possible in horizontal mode). Instead, it will be put *after* the current line.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new to latex.  What is Horizontal mode?